# how to display data on google map info window from database using php mysqli

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-markers

my sql query to fetch state count and state name that give me count and name of the state.
my problem is that i wanted to display multiple markers on google map from database. I need to display the data on click of marker on info window at google map im trying following code.

I'm not able to understand how to add loop in data.addRows.
or please let me know where I'm doing wrong

```
$sql = "SELECT `state`, COUNT(DISTINCT `sr_no`) AS `stateno` 
          FROM `Mystate` GROUP BY  `state`";
```

---

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {
      'packages': ['map'],
      // Note: you will need to get a mapsApiKey for your project.
      // See: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#load-settings
      'mapsApiKey': 'API_KEY'
    });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawMap);

    function drawMap () {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Address');
      data.addColumn('string', 'Location');
      data.addColumn('string', 'Marker')

      data.addRows([
        ['Mumbai, Maharashtra', 'India',   'blue' ],
        ['Pune, Maharashtra', 'India',  'green']
      ]);
      var url = 'https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons-land/vista-map-markers/48/';

      var options = {
        center: { lat: 20.5937, lng: 78.9629 },
        zoomLevel: 5,
        showTooltip: true,
        showInfoWindow: true,
        useMapTypeControl: true,
        icons: {
          blue: {
            normal:   url + 'Map-Marker-Ball-Azure-icon.png',
            selected: url + 'Map-Marker-Ball-Right-Azure-icon.png'
          },
          green: {
            normal:   url + 'Map-Marker-Push-Pin-1-Chartreuse-icon.png',
            selected: url + 'Map-Marker-Push-Pin-1-Right-Chartreuse-icon.png'
          },
          pink: {
            normal:   url + 'Map-Marker-Ball-Pink-icon.png',
            selected: url + 'Map-Marker-Ball-Right-Pink-icon.png'
          }
        }
      };
      var map = new google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'));

      map.draw(data, options);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map_div" style="height: 600px; width: 900px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This code works  with a small, unidentified, script error - the chart loads and the markers are plotted so this essentially becomes how to process the sql result. Perhaps studying [the various ways of creating a datatable](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datatables_dataviews) might help?

Comment: it not work for me

Comment: Does the database contain the colour you wish to apply for each location?

Answer (score 0):

It is **not** clear how you hope to select the colour of the marker, nor what you actually do with the `stateno` from the SQL query. That said, the JSON deata in the following is from one of my old databases and was used to emulate what your query **might** return. The actual task of processing this recordset and adding the data to the `dataTable` is done with an `Object.keys( json ).forEach` loop.

ie:

```
Object.keys( json ).forEach( key=>{
    let obj=json[ key ];
    data.addRow([
        obj.state, 'India', 'green'
    ]);
})
```

The full, working example with a hardcoded valud of `green` for the marker. I would suggest that this colour could be determined by the `stateno` data as that is not used but nothing in the above supports that. If that were the case a simple lookup of the `stateno` number against some sort of matrix of value/colour could be done.

I should possibly warn that running and testing this multiple times **could** lead to charges being raised against your apikey because of the need for each marker location needing to be geocoded in order to find the location.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src='https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js'></script>
        <script>
            const json=[
               {
                  "state":"Andaman and Nicobar Islands",
                  "stateno":"1"
               },
               {
                  "state":"Andhra Pradesh",
                  "stateno":"104"
               },
               {
                  "state":"Arunachal Pradesh",
                  "stateno":"1"
               },
               {
                  "state":"Assam",
                  "stateno":"15"
               },
               {
                  "state":"Bihar",
                  "stateno":"46"
               },
               {
                  "state":"Chandigarh",
                  "stateno":"1"
               },
               {
                  "state":"Chhattisgarh",
                  "stateno":"12"
               },
               {
                  "state":"Delhi",
                  "stateno":"29"
               },
               {
                  "state":"Goa",
                  "stateno":"3"
               },
               {
                  "state":"Gujarat",
                  "stateno":"63"
               },
               {
                  "state":"Haryana",
                  "stateno":"26"
               },
               {
                  "state":"Himachal Pradesh",
                  "stateno":"1"
               },
               {
                  "state":"Jammu and Kashmir",
                  "stateno":"8"
               },
               {
                  "state":"Jharkhand",
                  "stateno":"23"
               },
               {
                  "state":"Karnataka",
                  "stateno":"65"
               },
               {
                  "state":"Kerala",
                  "stateno":"32"
               },
               {
                  "state":"Madhya Pradesh",
                  "stateno":"53"
               },
               {
                  "state":"Maharashtra",
                  "stateno":"90"
               },
               {
                  "state":"Manipur",
                  "stateno":"1"
               },
               {
                  "state":"Meghalaya",
                  "stateno":"2"
               },
               {
                  "state":"Mizoram",
                  "stateno":"2"
               },
               {
                  "state":"Nagaland",
                  "stateno":"3"
               },
               {
                  "state":"Orissa",
                  "stateno":"22"
               },
               {
                  "state":"Pondicherry",
                  "stateno":"3"
               },
               {
                  "state":"Punjab",
                  "stateno":"34"
               },
               {
                  "state":"Rajasthan",
                  "stateno":"50"
               },
               {
                  "state":"Tamil Nadu",
                  "stateno":"85"
               },
               {
                  "state":"Tripura",
                  "stateno":"3"
               },
               {
                  "state":"Uttar Pradesh",
                  "stateno":"119"
               },
               {
                  "state":"West Bengal",
                  "stateno":"93"
               }
            ];
            google.charts.load('current', {
                'packages': ['map'],
                'mapsApiKey': 'AIzaSy..................04......tA'
            });
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawMap);

            function drawMap () {
                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                data.addColumn('string', 'Address');
                data.addColumn('string', 'Location');
                data.addColumn('string', 'Marker');
                
                
                /*
                data.addRows([
                    ['Mumbai, Maharashtra', 'India',   'blue' ],
                    ['Pune, Maharashtra', 'India',  'green']
                ]);
                */
                
                Object.keys( json ).forEach( key=>{
                    let obj=json[ key ];
                    data.addRow([
                        obj.state, 'India', 'green'
                    ]);
                })
                
                
                
                var url = 'https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons-land/vista-map-markers/48/';

                var options = {
                    center: { lat: 20.5937, lng: 78.9629 },
                    zoomLevel: 5,
                    showTooltip: true,
                    showInfoWindow: true,
                    useMapTypeControl: true,
                    icons: {
                        blue: {
                            normal:   url + 'Map-Marker-Ball-Azure-icon.png',
                            selected: url + 'Map-Marker-Ball-Right-Azure-icon.png'
                        },
                        green: {
                            normal:   url + 'Map-Marker-Push-Pin-1-Chartreuse-icon.png',
                            selected: url + 'Map-Marker-Push-Pin-1-Right-Chartreuse-icon.png'
                        },
                        pink: {
                            normal:   url + 'Map-Marker-Ball-Pink-icon.png',
                            selected: url + 'Map-Marker-Ball-Right-Pink-icon.png'
                        }
                    }
                };
                var map = new google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'));

                map.draw(data, options);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='map_div' style='height: 600px; width: 900px'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

**update**

Following on from comments about infoWindows etc I modified the working code I had to perform the lookup and return a different colour icon based upon arbitrary figures ( edit as appropriate if applicable ) and modified the data being added to the dataTable so that the 2nd argument contains the name & count - when the marker is clicked that will be displayed in the tooltip/infoWindow

```
const matrix={
    0:'blue',
    30:'green',
    75:'pink'
};

const lookup=(i)=>{
    let icon=false;
    Object.keys( matrix ).forEach( key=>{
        if( i > key ) icon=matrix[ key ];
    });
    return icon
};

Object.keys( json ).forEach( key=>{
    let obj=json[ key ];
    let icon=lookup( obj.stateno );
    
    data.addRow([
        obj.state, `${obj.state} - Count: ${obj.stateno}`, icon
    ])
});
```

Comment: leave the colour , if i wanted to display data from database only name of the state and count.   how can i display that in info window of google map

Comment: link this sample of google map https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple

Comment: You are not using the full google maps api - you are using google charts. I have never used this particular chart before but I don't believe it has access to the same `infoWindow` that you get in maps. If your db contained the latitude/longitude of each location adding markers and popping up an infowindow is easy

Comment: i have taken from google please have a look            https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/map#adding-multiple-marker-sets